# AS clause in oracle 11g XE

Tags: sql, oracle

tables: Primary keys have been highlighted

1. customer(**customer_id**,f_name,l_name,tel_no,addr,nic,city)
2. product(**product_id**,name,description,price,sales_tax)
3. branch(**branch_id**,name,tel_no,addr,city)
4. orders(**order_id**,customer_id,order_date,branch_id)
5. order_product(**order_id,product_id**,quantity)

This is a very simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(quantity) AS avg_quantity
FROM orders,order_product
WHERE orders.order_id = order_product.order_id
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING SUM(quantity) > (SELECT AVG(no_quantity)
FROM(
  SELECT customer_id, SUM(quantity) AS no_quantity
  FROM orders,order_product
  WHERE orders.order_id = order_product.order_id
  GROUP BY customer_id))
```

I have 2 sub-queries, i want to store the resultset temporarily while query execution.
i have seen SQL example that do this :

```
(SELECT * FROM orders WHERE branch_id = 4) AS tempone
```

I want to store the resultset so i can use it in upper level of sub query.The above query does not run in oracle sql developer.

```
ERROR : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

I don't want to use temporary tables. I've already tried WITH AS clause, the query takes too long to execute, as in more than 20 mins. I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to simplify this with:

```
select customer_id, avg_quantity
  from (select customer_id,
               sum(quantity) as avg_quantity,
               avg(sum(quantity)) over () global_avg_quantity
          from orders,
               order_product
         where orders.order_id = order_product.order_id
         group by customer_id)
 where avg_quantity > global_avg_quantity;
```

but i see you've put `SUM(quantity) AS avg_quantity`  sum of quantity = average?

Comment: Thank you, simplifies form is easier to read. sum of quantity isn't the average, the top level query displays the customer_id's and quantities of those customers whose quantity is greater than average, so i named it to make it easier for myself. **What i need right now is the "AS" clause in oracle so i can store temporary generated resultsets. If you have anything regarding that, i would be very grateful.**

Comment: @user1859596 the solution i presented removed the sub queries, so not sure why you're still looking in that direction. in Oracle, the way to store a resultset is the WITH clause (factored sub query) but its not needed in this case as we aren't reusing a result set over and over. you could, if you were going to reuse the result of my query above multiple times as part of a bigger sql, use `with res as (my query above) select..from res a, res b etc...`